# Display Block of R Code in Knitr With Evaluation Turned Off

Tags: r, knitr, overleaf

I am writing a document with fairly resource intensive R code. I want to prevent execution of one block of R code in knitr which is giving me document timeout error in Overleaf.

In R studio, this can be done using `eval = FALSE`. I want to recreate this in knitr. So far, the only way I have found is to suppress errors using `<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>= muffleError <- function(x,options) {}` but it only works on the entire document.

I specifically want to prevent evaluation but show the R code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to do, or have I misunderstood? The `eval = FALSE` is in one code chunk and the second chunk still plots.

````
---
title: "A Test Knit"
output: html_document
---

## Show code but don't run

```{r, eval = FALSE}
summary(cars)
```

## Run and render plot

```{r}
plot(pressure)
```
````